# How to fetch one column from another table using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a **Products** table:

ProductId

ProductDescription

CategoryId

And a **Categories** table:

CategoryId

CategoryDescription

***For every product, I would like to display a line like so:

Product Id | Product Description | **Category Description**

I have not been successful in forming the necessary mapping that is required for the above task.

*Products Mapping* I am using:

```
public ProductsMap()
{
    Table("Products");

    Id(x => x.ProductId);
    Map(x => x.ProductDescription);
    Map(x => x.CategoryId);

    References(x => x.Categories)
        .Column("CategoryId")
        .Not.Nullable();

    // Need Join() statement here?
    ...
```

My *Products* class:

```
public class Products
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }        
    public virtual int? CategoryDescription { get; set; } // Not in the db table.
}
```

My goal is to have the `CategoryDescription` field in the above class to be populated automatically by Fluent-NHibernate through the mapping specified.

I used the `join` statement suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247612/360840) but I got various exceptions for the following statement:

```
List<Products> products = session.Query<Products>().ToList();
```

Note: I can pull in all products from the database *without* the corresponding column in the Categories table, so I know that my database connectivity is good, and that the basic functionality of the application is sound.

I am new to Fluent-NHibernate, have invested quite a bit of time on this, but feel I am not getting anywhere. I would appreciate some directed guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused because you seem to mixing singular and plural, but I would create separate domain mappings for the product and category

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
}
```

map them the way you are mapping in the question, then create a view model

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
}
```

that gets populated with this query

```
        var products = session.Query<Products>().Select(p => new ProductViewModel()
        {
                ProductId =  p.ProductId,
                ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
                CategoryDescription = p.Category.CategoryDescription
        });
```

This will produce a query that only returns the columns you need.  If you return full entities, you are going to return information you don't need.

Comment: A huge thank you! It works. Now I have to understand **how** it works! :)  Any good resources you can suggest on Fluent-NHibernate?

Comment: PS: I had to use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3402839/360840 to resolve a cast problem, but other than that, it was perfect.

Comment: yeah the query i included will return an IQueryable.  ToList(), ToArray(),... will run the query an populate the list.

Comment: for your mapping questions, check this out http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html

Comment: I have been to that page, and had it bookmarked, but it didn't make sense at the time.  I have a book titled NHibernate 3 Beginner's Guide [2011] but it's old (for example, uses Null instead of Nullable), and not at all clear.  Spends too much on relational DB basics.  How did you learn, if I may ask?