# One-to-one NHibernate mapping where all fields map to properties in a single class

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a situation where the database has a one-to-one relationship between two tables which together clearly represent the same logical entity.

I would like to map these tables to the same class, and have properties of the class map to fields from BOTH tables. (I.E. rather than have one class compose another).

So if the tables are as follows:

**Table Foo**
Columns: Id (PK), Description, FavouriteCrispFlavour

**Table Bar**
Columns: Id (PK), NumberOfArms, EyeColour

I would like my class to look like the following:

```
public class FooBar
{
  public virtual int Id {get;set;)
  public virtual string Description {get;set;)
  public virtual CrispFlavour FavouriteCrispFlavour {get;set;)
  public virtual int NumberOfArms {get;set;)
  public virtual EyeColour EyeColour {get;set;)
}
```

Is this mapping possible in NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called a join mapping. You use the `<join>` element with a `table` attribute to compose an entity from multiple tables, for example:

```
<class name="MyClass">
  ...
  <join table="otherTable">
    <key column="MyClass_Id"/>
    <property name="propInOtherTable" />
  </join>
</class>
```

For a full (and better) description, see the [NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) on [join mappings](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-join).

Comment: Today, I love NHIbernate and Stack Overflow passionately. This page also describes how to achieve this sort of mapping in Fluent NHibernate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241005/how-to-join-table-in-fluent-nhibernate

Comment: Ha! I see from your website that you're something of an authority on Fluent NH yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you just need to specify the join in the HQL.