# (Fluent) NHibernate: Map field from separate table into object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm currently trying to get (Fluent)NHibernate to map an object to our legacy database schema. There are three tables involved.

- Table a contains most information of the actual object I need to retrieve
- Table b is a table which connects table a with table c
- Table c has one additional field I need for the object

An SQL query to retrieve the information looks like this:

```
SELECT z.ID, z.ZANR, e.TDTEXT 
FROM   PUB.table_a z 
JOIN   PUB.table_b t ON (t.TDKEY = 602) 
JOIN   PUB.table_c e ON (e.ID = t.ID AND e.TDNR = z.ZANR) 
WHERE  z.ZANR = 1;
```

The main problem is how to specify these two join conditions in the mapping.

Entity for table a looks like this:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Name should map to the column table_c.TDTEXT.

The mapping I have so far is this:

```
public class EntityAMap : ClassMap<EntityA>
{
    public EntityAMap()
    {
        Table("PUB.table_a");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.Number).Column("ZANR");
    }
}
```

I tried to map the first join with the same strategy as in [How to join table in fluent nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241005/how-to-join-table-in-fluent-nhibernate), however this will not work, because I do not have a direct reference from table_a to table_b, the only thing connecting them is the constant number 602 (see SQL-query above).

I didn't find a way to specify that constant in the mapping somehow.

Comment: What do your entities look like? What mapping have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could map the name as readonly property easily

```
public EntityAMap()
{
    Table("PUB.table_a");

    Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");

    // if ZANR always has to be 1
    Where("ZANR = 1");

    Map(x => x.Number).Column("ZANR");
    Map(x => x.Name).Formula("(SELECT c.TDTEXT FROM PUB.table_b b JOIN PUB.table_c c ON (c.ID = b.ID AND b.TDKEY = 602 AND c.TDNR = ZANR))");
}
```

Update: i could only imagine a hidden reference and the name property delegating to there

```
public EntityAMap()
{
    HasOne(Reveal.Member<EntityA>("hiddenEntityC"));
}

public class EntityB
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}

public EntityCMap()
{
    Where("Id = (SELECT b.Id FROM PUB.table_b b WHERE b.TDKEY = 602)");

    References(x => x.EntityA).PropertyRef(x => x.Number);
}
```

Comment: Problem is the underlying database engine does not support subqueries in the SELECT phrase, only in the WHERE statement.
Also, we need to be able to modify this value.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. However it is not very practical, as we need various entities that will reference Entity C with different TDKEYs. Maybe I'll just map entity B / C without A referencing them and use a glue class.
Accepting your answer because it solves the problem.

Comment: you can reference EntityC as often as you want with different where clauses. You'll need to define an entityname different for each of them and specify it in the has one.