# NHibernate column alternative mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have table columns with table number suffix

```
create table T1234_DATA (CHANGEUSER_1234 nvarchar(50), ...)
```

For tables I wrote fluent mapping. When used directly it works fine, but there are (for some historical reason) many views or stored procedures which are aliasing columns to generic suffic `_0001`:

```
create view v1234_DATA as select CHANGEUSER_1234 as CHANGEUSER_0001
```

Whenever I want to use such view I have to write full class mapping again. Is there some sort of alternative column mapping in Fluent or HBM to share it between all named queries? Wildcards in sql column names, selecting alternative class mapping on the query, multiple sql columns mapped to single property, etc.?

Comment: You'd explain your scenario in more details, in case you really want to get help here. But for sure NHibernate mapping is not "dynamic" in runtime. Simply once Factory is created, all configuration is settled down. Each entity each property do have ONE table/column mapping. No way (no reason) to change that...

Comment: I'm not sure what detail are you missing. I got table column and view where this column is aliased. I need to load both to one entity. Now I have to create separate mapping for each query which is using aliased view. I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, a Join could solve the problem.
As you can see in:
[NHibernate Mapping - <join/>](http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join)
[How to join table in fluent nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241005/how-to-join-table-in-fluent-nhibernate)

Or maybe you could use a formula (or some formulas) like:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
    public User() {
        Table("TB_USER");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.ChangeUser1234, "CHANGEUSER_1234");

        Map(x => x.ChangeUser0001)
            .Formula("(select CHANGEUSER_0001 from TABLE where ...)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, your answer is completly out of my problem, but I see how to extend my question to get some valid answer.